# How to disable softKeyboard if there is a hardware Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

Actually i'm checking by this method if there is a hardware keyboard on my device

```
 private boolean isHardwareKeyboardAvailable() { return getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard != Configuration.KEYBOARD_NOKEYS; }
```

But now i would be able to disable the softKeyboard for that activity if the result of that boolean is true. How can i do?

Actually for a target of devices i set in my manifest

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

But i have to disable even it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is by preventing the keyboard from popping up automatically:

`this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

Put this code when you realized that the phone has physical keyboard.